# Unable to open EMS file type using Perl OPEN - but opens when the content is copied to notepad

Tags: perl

I am unable to open a large EMS Format file using Perl OPEN. But, when the same content is manually copied to notepad, the one in notepad opens. I don't want to do the manual copy, please let me how I can open the file with EMS file type.

Here is the code I am using, it works with .txt file, but not the .ems file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# open a filehandle to data.txt
open( IN, "C:\\Users\\test\\Documents\\lOGS\\Testing\hourly.txt" ) || die('cannot open file: ' . $!);

my @Required = ( 28, 385, 38, 708, 722, 379, 380, 32, 76, 388, 389, 62, 739, 319, 83 );

for ( 1 .. 2 ) {
    <IN>;
}

while ( my $line = <IN> ) {
    my @fields = split( /:/, $line );

    for ( $count = 0 ; $count <= 15 ; $count++ ) {
        if ( $fields[0] == $Required[$count] ) {
            print $line;
        }
    }
}

# close the filehandle and exit
close(IN);
exit;
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using open? It is harder to answer questions abouts programming languages without seeing any code.

Comment: The open works with all text files though except this particular file type

Comment: 'Unaable to open' What does that mean? Do you get a message, what is it?

Comment: Cannot open file: No such file or directory at test.pl ...also gives a line number where Open statment is present....

Comment: Are you sure you didn't typo "lOGS" ? Should that not be "Logs"?

Comment: Actually the names of the directories is modified from what is use...But never mind the script itself works with all other text files without any problems..its only doesn't open files with file type EMS

Answer (score 0):

The EMS format is not a simple block of text. Different file formats exist such as DOC, DOCX, EMS. You can open all those using standard utilities such as Notepad, and Wordpad. However, just because you see text displayed, does not mean that is the only data inside those files. What makes a DOC file a DOC file? There is a standard specification that describes the file format, such as header data (how do you tell the OS it's a DOC file?) and where data is stored (where do you store the # of pages, the fonts used, the actual text?).

The EMS file is like that as well. I don't have experience or an easy specification sheet about the EMS format, but perhaps you can use http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html to open the file and read the data in bytes and then search for the text information that you want. That's reverse engineering for you.